# Property does not exist on type 'function'

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the firebase.auth method in a function using typescript and I am getting a Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function' (ts 2339). I must be missing something simple here, however not quite sure what it is.

```
const registerUser = (email: String, password: String) => {
  console.log(email, password);
  return (firebase.auth as Function)
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userObj: Object) => console.log(email, password, userObj))
    .catch((error: Error) => console.log('Error logging in.', error));
};
```

The problem happens with the .createUserWithEmailAndPassword

PROBLEM SOLVED: I tried to solve the problem by casting firebase.auth as type Function, it is easily solved by removing that and calling it by firebase.auth()

Comment: Why are you casting `firebase.auth` to `Function`?  That seems wrong.  Your TypeScript should look idential to the JavaScript in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_up_new_users

Comment: Me changing it to auth() fixed the problem, I thought I could fix it by casting it as type Function

Answer (score 0):

You have your line here:

```
return (firebase.auth as Function)
```

And the error you're getting is `Property does not exist on type 'function'`

Are you sure `firebase.auth` is actually a function? If it really is a function it should be something like `firebase.auth()` <- the missing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the API the way it was intended, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_up_new_users):

```
  return firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    ...
```